# Formatar o valor do ComboBox puxado do banco SQL (LINQ) em Projeto C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, number-format

Preciso de uma ajuda no código abaixo...Preciso fazer com que o valor Float puxado do Banco SQL fique no formato brasileiro do Conjunto dos Números Reais num projeto em C# (WPF) em uma ComboBox (como Double). Ou seja, trazer ele como String no IntemsSource e não ficar nesse formato "0.000", e sim neste "0,000".

Código:

```
var query_Fardo = from f in oDB.tabProdutos 
                  where f.Codigo == Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoApontaPrd.Text) 
                  select f.Fardo;
CmBox_FardoApontaPrd.ItemsSource = query_Fardo;
CmBox_FardoApontaPrd.ItemStringFormat = "0,000";//Não funciona
```

Grato pelo apoio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi bem se queria que o tipo ficasse como `Double`, porém segue uma resposta transformando para `string`:

```
var query_Fardo = from f in oDB.tabProdutos 
                  where f.Codigo == Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoApontaPrd.Text) 
                  select f.Fardo.ToString("#,###.###");
```

Com isso, não seria necessário

> CmBox_FardoApontaPrd.ItemStringFormat = "0,000";

Comment: Como o CmBox_FardoApontaPrd é uma String é preciso converter o Float em String...Mas ele precisa aparecer como Double (número Real)...O valor é tipo "0,000" ex.: 1,020; 1,920...Entende?

Comment: Esse método f.Fardo.ToString("#,###.###") não tem conversões suportadas em SQL.

Comment: `oDB` é de que tipo?

Comment: Uso LINQ to SQL...na Tabela tabProdutos a coluna Fardo é Float...E puxo assim: TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext oDB = new TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext()

Comment: Isso ajuda? Não entendi quando pergunta o tipo oDB...Uso o SQL Server

Comment: Tente converter em uma lista com nessa questão sua anterior: `var oProdutos = (from Selecao in oDB.tabProdutos orderby Selecao.Descricao select Selecao).ToList<tabProduto>();` depois tente `.ToString("#,###.###");`

Comment: Não deu certo! :(